# Does "if" Interrupt a "while" function?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to solve the problem sets of CS50.
Task is, to recover jpegs from data.
My code produces jpegs, but it seems to take just one chunk of 512 bytes instead of the whole picture.
Does my "if" interrupt my "while" condition.

Here my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const int FAT_SIZE = 512;

typedef uint8_t FAT [FAT_SIZE];

typedef  uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover card.raw\n");
        return 1;
    }

     // Open files and determine scaling factor
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FAT fats;
    int number = 0;
    char filename[8];
    FILE *jpg;

    // Going through the input file
    while (fread(&fats, 512, 1, input))
    {
        if (fats[0] == 0xff && fats[1] == 0xd8 && fats[2] == 0xff && (fats[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            if (number == 0)
            {
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg" , 0);
                jpg = fopen(filename, "w");
                number++;
                fwrite(&fats,512, 1, jpg);
            } else {
                fclose(jpg);
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg" , number);
                number++;
                jpg = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(&fats,512, 1, jpg);
            }
        }   
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(jpg);
    return 0;
}
```

I found a solution , but I want to understand, why my code is wrong
I didnt write following code. It's written by [JosephR](https://joseph28robinson.medium.com/cs50-pset4-recover-c1133101547e) , it's just for comparision.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
    printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
    return 1;
    }
        else
    {
        // Open card.raw
        char *input_file_name = argv[1];
        FILE *input_pointer = fopen(input_file_name, "r");

        if (input_pointer == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: cannot open %s\n", input_file_name);
            return 2;
        }

        // Initialise variables
        BYTE buffer[512];
        int count = 0;
        FILE *img_pointer = NULL;
        char filename[8];

        // Repeat until end of card:
        while (fread(&buffer, 512, 1, input_pointer) == 1)
        {
            // If start of a new JPEG (0xff 0xd8 0xff 0xe*):
            if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
            {
                // If not first JPEG, close previous
                if (!(count == 0))
                {
                    fclose(img_pointer);
                }
                // Initialise file
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count);
                img_pointer = fopen(filename, "w");
                count++;
            }
            // If JPEG has been found, write to file
            if (!(count == 0))
            {
                fwrite(&buffer, 512, 1, img_pointer);
            }
        }
        fclose(input_pointer);
        fclose(img_pointer);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The inner `if/else` only executes when the outer `if` is true.

Comment: Since all the writing happens inside the `if`, nothing is written unless the condition is true. In the second version you have an `fwrite()` outside the condition about the first 4 bytes of the buffer.

Comment: OT: `const int FAT_SIZE = 512;`

`typedef uint8_t FAT [FAT_SIZE];` is valid not C code. You would need a *real* constant.

Comment: @anastaciu or compile it using C++ compiler. And it is quite common here

Comment: @Barmar Do I understand it correctly, that the first 512bytes are copied into the newfile, but the copying stops, because the first if condition becomes false for the next 512bytes chunk?

Comment: If the `if` condition is only true for the 1st 512-byte chunk, that's true.

Comment: Why do you have the `if (number == 0)` condition? You do the same thing in both `if` and `else`.